# Why does FreeBSD's implementation of memchr increment its pointer in its condition?

Tags: c, freebsd

[FreeBSD's generic implementation of `memchr`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/11/lib/libc/string/memchr.c?view=markup) does:

```
void *
memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n)
{
    if (n != 0) {
        const unsigned char *p = s;

        do {
            if (*p++ == (unsigned char)c)
                return ((void *)(p - 1));
        } while (--n != 0);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

which to me seems unnecessarily complicated; the initial `n != 0` check with `do`-`while` just to avoid the `p` declaration seems completely pointless.  However, I am particularly interested in why the loop body does:

```
if (*p++ == (unsigned char)c)
    return ((void *)(p - 1));
```

instead of a more straightforward:

```
if (*p == (unsigned char)c)
    return ((void *) p);
++p;
```

Does inlining the post-increment with the condition have some optimization benefit for some compiler/platform?

Comment: Did you check the machine code the compiler generates (with optimisations)? How that differs from whatever your approach would be? Does the _definition_ of `p` generate code at all? And yes, you miss to consider when that code most likely was written and how good/bad compilers optimised back then. Quite some CPUs have a "decrement and branch if not zero" instruction.

Comment: @Olaf I did use godbolt to compare implementations with gcc (using -O3 and again with -Os).  I am not fluent with assembly, but the straightforward version seems to generate fewer instructions.

Comment: Re-read my comment, I added quite a lot. You check on every target running BSD? x86 is not really a widely spread platform. The code could even be used for 8 and 16 bit MCUs which outnumber x86 and ARM by decades still.

Comment: @Olaf I did not test all BSD targets. That's why I'm asking, and the things you mentioned are what I'm looking for in an answer.

Comment: Problem is rationalising why a specific code was written is pure speculation. Most times even the pgrogrammer cannot explain every single LOC. IOW: Your question is opinionated and no good fit for SO. That's why I will not answer - sorry.

Comment: I don't see why an answer must necessarily be opinion-based.  I don't actually care about what the author intended; I want to know if there is or ever was any advantage to writing the code that way.  I don't think it's unreasonable to expect an answer like, "This construct makes it easier for compiler X targeting platform Y to generate better code".

Comment: The question in the topic *is* opinion-based, as some people might consider this code to be *unnecessarily complicated*, while **most** will consider this code to be *basic*.

Comment: In fact, it's so *basic* that it doesn't warrant rewriting and retesting, let alone these keystrokes. If it isn't broken, don't fix it... and if you're going to fix *this*, you might as well use the same internal justification to choose a better programming language.

Comment: The code in question [use to use the `register` keyword](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/string/memchr.c?annotate=1573#l51), so the wrapping could have prevented unnecessary register allocation.  `*p++` is a fairly common C idiom, possibly more so in BSD code because of its history; purely speculation, but its original use may have been to help C compilers generate combined load/increment instructions (similar to what @Olaf suggested), or to save a line of vertical space.

Comment: n is a size_t (i.e. unsigned). The n != 0 check is necessary if you want to decrement it. Give this is likely rather old code there was probably a benefit to doing that rather than creating a second counter variable in the past.

As for your second point, I think kdhp covered it well.

Comment: If you get _really_ curious you could try asking the [original author](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/string/memchr.c?annotate=1573#l5), though the code does date from [BSD4.3-Tahoe (1988)](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/memchr.3?annotate=1.10).

Comment: @JarraMcIntyre The initial `if` could be removed if the `do` ... `while (--n != 0)` were replaced with just `while (n-- != 0)` (but that's not actually the part I'm curious about).

Comment: @kdhp: The `register` keyword is completely deprecated for modern compilers wrt register allocation. It's only use now is reporting an error if the address of such a variable is taken.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, that is likely why it was removed, but the structure appears to be an artifact of when it was written, before the keyword became unnecessary.

Comment: @kdhp: Removed from what? The code? It is definitively still part of the standard (IIRC, Jens Gustedt recently proposed it for additional semantics; just can't recall the details)

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, [the `register` keyword](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/11/lib/libc/string/memchr.c?r1=86170&r2=92889) was previously removed from the referenced code.

Comment: The code dates from when Vaxes ruled the earth. *p++ would use the autoincrement register addressing mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case of the pointer post-increment is to allow compilers of the era (e.g. PCC) to use the auto-increment addressing mode in DEC machines (like Mark Plotnick mentions in a comment).

Since all DEC machines support auto-increment addressing, this way of coding loops was once very common (BTW, the m68k supports the same optimization).

The `do-while` loop on the other hand is simply because on a naïf compiler it tends to yield better code, not just to avoid setting `p`.

Neither *should* do any difference on a modern compiler.

Comment: Avoiding setting `p` does save an instruction, of course

Comment: Would not make any difference, for a naïf compiler, it only changes the position of the branch, and that's only significant for `n=0`.

Answer (score 3):

*First: This is pure speculation. I have not written this code nor could I verify my guess.*

There's one very important semantic difference between those two versions of the code:

```
// Version A
if (*p++ == (unsigned char)c)
    return ((void *)(p - 1));

// Version B
if (*p == (unsigned char)c)
    return ((void *) p);
++p;
```

In version A the increment is sequenced before the code block of that `if`, whereas in version B it is sequenced after that block.

Thus in version A the increment code will be placed before the branch instruction which is likely generated from the `if`. At least we can IMO assume such a relatively direct translation from C code to assembly from compilers of the time when the code was written (1988?).

> Does inlining the post-increment with the condition have some
>   optimization benefit for some compiler/platform?

Having the increment before the branch allows for a relatively simple optimisation on architectures whose branch instructions have a [delay slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot): you can move the increment into that delay slot instead of having a NOP there.

So version A needs one instruction less per loop iteration than version B, at the cost of a single decrement when the function returns. It's a (micro) optimisation.